# How to Input Data Into a Trained Neural Network Algorithm - MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, neural-network

This is very basic, but I can't seem to find an answer online...

I have developed a neural network for classification using MATLAB. However, I would like to feed to trained algorithm a new dataset for prediction in a prospective manner. I can't seem to figure out the formatting for the function myNeuralNetworkFunction(X,~,~). What goes into X, ~, and ~? If I put random number values in those three spots ie. myNeuralNetworkFunction(1,2,3) it will output

ans =

```
0.4793
0.3524
0.1683
```

Is this interpreted as the probability that sample fits into Class I, Class II, and Class III respectively?

Thank you for the help, I know these are newbie questions.

Below is the code for the neural network:

```
function [Y,Xf,Af] = myNeuralNetworkFunction(X,~,~)
%MYNEURALNETWORKFUNCTION neural network simulation function.
%
% Generated by Neural Network Toolbox function genFunction, 25-Sep-2014 13:48:20.
% 
% [Y] = myNeuralNetworkFunction(X,~,~) takes these arguments:
% 
%   X = 1xTS cell, 1 inputs over TS timsteps
%   Each X{1,ts} = 24xQ matrix, input #1 at timestep ts.
% 
% and returns:
%   Y = 1xTS cell of 1 outputs over TS timesteps.
%   Each Y{1,ts} = 3xQ matrix, output #1 at timestep ts.
% 
% where Q is number of samples (or series) and TS is the number of timesteps.

%#ok<*RPMT0>

  % ===== NEURAL NETWORK CONSTANTS =====

  % Input 1
  x1_step1_xoffset = [14.8911704312115;15.2767639519654;0.51064;1.90413;33.60375;15.43632;24.71805;0.01846;4.981;0.00033;0.22159;39.32377;19.36387;9.81086;0.22033;4.6786;14.9629;8.8028;4.74512;0.55702;660.25663;8.59155;0.37416;17.83039];
  x1_step1_gain = [0.027354428009736;0.0612618147797722;0.53764452556903;0.108070429498904;0.00273415535440648;0.0167784432574442;0.00143874231937304;0.483828047511914;0.499625281039221;0.652986597450087;1.59790355054169;0.00545387219881284;0.018425510635389;0.00896113957019686;0.837910418997105;0.00686875293360145;0.00614397382765453;0.0196487182502502;0.10665671204021;1.48306341579166;0.000773677797796089;0.0480697241735192;0.314333448065042;0.00523034792222075];
  x1_step1_ymin = -1;

  % Layer 1
  b1 = [1.55987050956456;1.3844896446184087;1.1858356678234501;-1.0437094397090567;-0.7695743943051927;0.7727728185085837;-0.49850097623420581;0.3360196027312633;-0.5052450230407648;0.12573629438984127;-0.36142377450191465;-0.26512162787695787;0.43422049198818885;-0.59484996326687367;-0.74347840297622803;-1.1241254208475855;1.0621269773342072;-1.1217914200306649;1.4625923192101142;-1.5876844882508814];
  IW1_1 = [-0.055982436209679104 -0.28944502014743512 0.38896483763687473 -0.17520091781902516 -0.36788963119290879 0.58680010891648471 0.38941048594029137 0.010330200046712359 -0.049196997026008424 -0.25965095783883646 -0.02330444839336468 0.48471956663410432 0.35540617499483801 -0.34500146111020641 -0.0306422432801076 -0.20558648541285637 -0.48852403830931596 0.58018036801883965 -0.21778584198672668 -0.17639473933123317 -0.12894993242501401 -0.32191664913965018 0.36502076112253562 -0.35423424394067804;-0.44842057227554855 0.39700388069390274 0.18239852514402061 0.33330369404033905 -0.33083266709586073 -0.42109550142439961 -0.37936412673907055 0.14092987565726023 0.27498893910037497 -0.037696461239827603 0.42058106837803533 -0.35405721057928519 -0.31200898537356103 0.3266151312604435 0.24758020461158411 -0.00028318649770493406 0.48622068190587153 -0.050159207180306711 0.038521280211102946 -0.43752851101801921 -0.40917699558077231 -0.31417436789272912 -0.30924992912408938 0.38587651437275444;-0.23169755933546252 -0.033754347614425945 -0.43966963319617031 -0.10362737153323315 -0.23869583433068692 -0.018842535943556636 -0.27934947951447109 -0.43974815194076045 -0.33977835068587897 0.17162613017120945 -0.36065553178060761 -0.39840592499124527 -0.10812891657493709 -0.39993101606248699 0.19264396978343784 -0.56134807445038559 -0.3646549207685566 0.03693663630665505 0.28992344266856157 -0.24197846571776097 -0.28421945026123852 0.2238898665802749 0.57957009993848951 0.52865696060643663;0.46775595437716078 -0.49759398923140102 -0.25543635820865557 0.18011414654693347 0.22839857302768798 -0.39817052105690232 0.42124548524474159 -0.38302040274848675 -0.45018774604344564 0.30776271594062077 -0.053687146243323117 0.21008425591895208 -0.25086014236085991 0.46442044353123357 0.37013016450855851 -0.35562597240295934 0.48246075163860352 -0.22143337282043704 -0.15354622986226024 -0.19520148498923329 0.28175659072346265 -0.19991745788738577 -0.265495614539076 -0.32998007941199758;0.53314385759977978 -0.084288099570861252 -0.087904814731226133 0.13997887906328665 0.078583762374498448 0.22089986106370055 0.11937406236219919 0.17931986738852818 -0.45555526826525045 0.10273619071622088 0.15437971971424042 0.19671926437767534 -0.30373240551984354 0.32987810978703014 0.33946655924729924 -0.33172198600185432 0.15007897699613323 0.44305909871884158 -0.45965277545665773 -0.5445260477144781 0.53690386149310154 0.32071960639735619 0.3346706317427332 -0.60044551394561885;-0.21895079613669227 0.30360131864707257 -0.48254331869669026 0.5426234966667407 0.53175788259274104 0.43438569989221498 0.25674366269228105 -0.20235539069140043 0.05522085113210641 -0.35628856718433854 0.1805462722036959 -0.20232926059522438 -0.56741148515447382 -0.24436414572936965 0.27639712244441805 0.35074056368620099 -0.33877374004680966 -0.38162031513538591 0.061523677180970113 -0.20635757815991357 0.17478209045151902 0.14373440637723872 0.4140189252683093 0.086756882167071767;0.20194393498084873 0.33601377745253913 -0.10774209305964288 -0.29722624992594709 0.30223692004740155 -0.41190860275852431 0.32459858890469206 -0.4103664016524477 0.1718744178031123 0.36646047872493631 0.24021043279112594 -0.47527338312608136 0.45522056842903807 0.4663571072074067 -0.15619524330182147 0.17042159594600717 -0.0094643117123553756 0.34972229572902347 -0.35841045332376159 0.44184179501847487 0.50657491877032257 -0.27251535338974842 0.053976124783220322 -0.45817262113177243;-0.48112733765313997 -0.15382945548644572 0.59568206101452548 0.071917432620535626 0.14546994145938053 -0.029054476752923268 -0.44239514130279495 -0.49288663170035307 0.61976876211435661 -0.35515864087981674 -0.26095866399195611 -0.49938787137002588 0.041803130505081311 0.35681709414517526 -0.24095955980424952 0.26090619437256735 0.27496224831511668 -0.10807493710234177 0.11792476953631001 0.12084195942242892 0.13552026682635013 0.26233519005540168 0.48436137135289897 0.41261415007384206;0.21895780734810372 -0.1511323910665277 -0.30822548003275396 -0.33710575421358474 0.034674652442276827 0.15101859650020807 -0.011485449807831588 -0.25985968754425742 -0.43197950537600155 0.43497607287821932 -0.064820281951947667 -0.073022254701932118 0.015714438133674614 -0.023776065260460819 0.34997606652439067 0.37469844465000585 -0.25689851488533372 0.51569778564256707 -0.44838098074602389 0.31305831108437643 0.51306142767010743 -0.40214657636097817 -0.41763716358690595 0.45699543228831752;-0.53017416936845407 0.42831417232332336 0.11786784798380144 0.039227806546526515 -0.29763012137133199 0.24637901223770131 0.29762857397361714 -0.013347397012488965 -0.4627281529891169 0.24554434668388281 0.39129352061411959 0.379553553064787 0.04415707626655066 -0.11971558212994232 -0.15276429992136409 0.45228689028401242 -0.50322528984760739 0.046552169551343309 -0.37788000442556102 -0.29612757986196442 0.33798412345818085 0.069089800822850531 -0.49046720164829072 0.26511335230057065;0.20196677020567266 0.095488430461431573 0.16399244062844004 0.52716962232017073 0.4348012802986464 0.018067285639911158 -0.26705074363994968 0.48825114495670008 0.14127835124956273 0.24629868830206755 0.54017198057440774 0.06480510843471024 -0.022685160228366745 -0.15438176399914305 -0.43132627576811389 -0.13129532598575516 0.096451476137207587 0.5926396743011304 0.091208771991736159 0.42720517218438908 -0.29783725969092761 0.65683408878263738 0.36153177278145338 -0.22919208447591802;-0.50452115900815619 0.0030003517081181488 0.46134789637779744 -0.60227711400545947 -0.48214549250915872 0.013063050810550585 0.15135559839444082 0.39143093064769241 -0.14086525474058859 -0.21731704108556071 -0.054170772583192923 -0.49764000322426905 -0.30456997680804121 0.18375313948369021 0.41927012683947518 0.19128196902407038 -0.37761853390034739 -0.26576194181536378 0.07726206216389829 -0.38520339916841162 0.025887458179402578 -0.11906795914922447 -0.56692586761027453 0.13538403175109057;0.35891662644586675 -0.37425630339293836 -0.13087333241744242 -0.16492608364523814 -0.47868126798293337 -0.29135042798915084 -0.32892700173155859 -0.41341689342409382 -0.47684656050809077 -0.40828991848978646 -0.22424380129271532 0.29329791200577621 0.52835706198039978 -0.24064601775448177 -0.078866115462040517 0.29104242992340346 -0.24155428609588137 -0.12412108758956597 -0.12661134901318469 0.53644335880766647 0.12353437383200713 0.044443354598736433 0.21915106707248028 0.45738952754175133;-0.4006229555345403 -0.38491870113799098 0.12684216755732858 0.23789761071382912 0.25780049722498549 0.12128670064482043 0.35455194739691609 -0.4402274458485313 0.26906181992343847 0.57958726634921054 -0.025706324845669152 0.16140130401483566 -0.060519286269974548 -0.49816799130907657 -0.32786559565987894 0.16032470166880464 0.47671706759696875 0.12126382162524643 0.11497301319122195 -0.060984633499597526 0.46572964627020685 0.53029114632588248 0.34913629799983792 0.3783603854876138;-0.23751836785709313 0.48943920219833192 -0.29803103360979344 0.51154553661021629 -0.10243898977969999 0.1738700091501662 0.40995996639230364 0.39877231971176491 0.019918105182817482 0.15560102498926082 -0.098114106905600795 -0.15612390887354927 0.17301979172967061 0.567425194056702 -0.53484903500060321 0.17128726452515966 -0.34133214953438257 0.36482792066829411 0.40500232676302061 -0.3046651610223628 0.14649536078138331 -0.23949813135658626 -0.36393981963734012 0.22581701137418828;-0.40046957858520676 0.6034617628482869 -0.48336085729216799 0.086551313937414401 0.11485328389518146 0.069661771564103803 0.047510680842533633 -0.14211127107043481 0.22762855836704607 -0.21910785086188639 -0.29622202947083798 0.010467063845525388 0.23958478560501784 0.47212874176804626 0.1021228950976064 -0.36988758340717282 0.43616237795047241 -0.34513066977461881 0.14396012746107209 0.17986038875407201 0.48818701767399414 0.28917556942311645 -0.10086763238985247 0.33793394200564547;0.46284253016065918 -0.13727771516669529 0.13577149568213143 0.58818192843346606 -0.20148925476427895 -0.46029269863375366 -0.11294539393881832 0.024584643894249029 0.096542815957358211 -0.47936958224293125 -0.38391418257758381 -0.0060708736228519012 0.31378810959162057 0.29455211667194553 -0.14010352441871604 -0.33539638866126609 -0.15418382335315545 -0.53468970341166444 -0.14260673859838446 -0.1588041819874888 -0.38130427331586136 -0.3152783892401666 -0.13797679272406654 0.41318952672339815;-0.0037580606519731774 0.25559446638500755 0.20805798628313835 -0.1197347663038016 0.25029241343311948 -0.19266109493430622 0.52557544297059011 -0.1619733303821082 -0.59587716408971514 -0.37733940188634407 -0.36931374243099563 0.035618524883801912 -0.36574413766651082 0.62552801072201847 -0.15345989677803071 -0.26277675374506049 -0.69325217331710443 -0.19889757010483353 0.080406773105486662 0.075152499178945523 -0.2528234547543543 0.47888754226850988 0.44361594565071144 0.13773610213966411;0.20986694884019669 0.5838069905096277 -0.24368635959982227 -0.31599013988815555 -0.18540921192951351 0.10603309773028717 -0.67295724327081385 -0.24897469750728726 0.19173947449901921 0.51005578175094068 -0.015723561815696684 0.1587217224633255 -0.29884049261948881 -0.0039568545329125258 -0.1061339521622824 0.16201250459705921 -0.28062245454944174 0.10496187687903319 -0.34786621560772413 0.32270413963798411 -0.054666413518356639 -0.31614441259179926 -0.25305596431344596 -0.62685043098789994;-0.44657252161722044 0.40823814755654514 0.064212018038187074 0.0066019305589507665 0.25098026347930169 -0.18569199430015434 -0.11776683585309426 0.46833540687344827 -0.19916527198638995 -0.2905264441725523 -0.45266095490372243 -0.34687790231020543 0.2229130626291119 -0.38366535966479787 0.017187383060134738 -0.29935260697370364 -0.38314823395341346 0.44303063064199694 0.2368545199511122 0.35728303698551611 -0.42103390461422724 0.37014001452647027 0.38735250852526876 -0.23260623539266509];

  % Layer 2
  b2 = [0.25980539367757699;0.58647489488472682;-1.065941024916949];
  LW2_1 = [0.070686644098666221 -0.62704849467284407 -0.26668403380813344 -0.60847661573672651 0.49634405645024138 0.96115472226825938 0.70161314683215703 -0.16244831393351064 -0.38778721201635435 -0.82737438162882337 -0.24871150318794885 0.33797064247996977 0.53933794530594548 -0.37673777430541439 0.66603786612798555 -0.86058356658893731 -0.1846439763729246 0.25597795984504707 0.88301766928111958 0.70154602431628132;-0.27224631592661641 -0.46534028660614779 0.31748339396483055 -0.77568458059698819 -0.19985189513930471 0.058899860449242475 -0.10649552828923813 0.59251644442143325 0.54884630250946731 -0.74722920996123465 0.78936347266716889 0.68795991441040816 -0.11649640733421024 0.88899475748526757 -0.27752223550178284 0.12836172010559904 0.34304188529668661 -0.3303334581681488 0.26083195268179116 0.28358224497140561;0.67722868060993668 -0.73839160801059034 -0.52668020024017737 -0.42037687153952519 0.42608979733760222 -0.085145700117314219 0.40224829869858036 -0.4380368280033714 0.22960637835244566 -0.61906073689858399 0.55422321506755923 -0.15626454164673309 0.58835836575191547 -0.89973441932108511 -0.77901845165683903 0.77329875011083038 -0.68252063535418506 -0.80613188132936098 0.85129342660612917 0.86638907626986761];

  % ===== SIMULATION ========

  % Format Input Arguments
  isCellX = iscell(X);
  if ~isCellX, X = {X}; end;

  % Dimensions
  TS = size(X,2); % timesteps
  if ~isempty(X)
    Q = size(X{1},2); % samples/series
  else
    Q = 0;
  end

  % Allocate Outputs
  Y = cell(1,TS);

  % Time loop
  for ts=1:TS

    % Input 1
    Xp1 = mapminmax_apply(X{1,ts},x1_step1_gain,x1_step1_xoffset,x1_step1_ymin);

    % Layer 1
    a1 = tansig_apply(repmat(b1,1,Q) + IW1_1*Xp1);

    % Layer 2
    a2 = softmax_apply(repmat(b2,1,Q) + LW2_1*a1);

    % Output 1
   Y{1,ts} = a2;
  end

  % Final Delay States
  Xf = cell(1,0);
  Af = cell(2,0);

  % Format Output Arguments
  if ~isCellX, Y = cell2mat(Y); end
end

% ===== MODULE FUNCTIONS ========

% Map Minimum and Maximum Input Processing Function
function y = mapminmax_apply(x,settings_gain,settings_xoffset,settings_ymin)
  y = bsxfun(@minus,x,settings_xoffset);
  y = bsxfun(@times,y,settings_gain);
  y = bsxfun(@plus,y,settings_ymin);
end

% Competitive Soft Transfer Function
function a = softmax_apply(n)
  nmax = max(n,[],1);
  n = bsxfun(@minus,n,nmax);
  numer = exp(n);
  denom = sum(numer,1); 
  denom(denom == 0) = 1;
  a = bsxfun(@rdivide,numer,denom);
end

% Sigmoid Symmetric Transfer Function
function a = tansig_apply(n)
  a = 2 ./ (1 + exp(-2*n)) - 1;
end
```

Comment: I can't answer your question fully because I don't know about neural networks, but I can tell you that in MATLAB `~` means 'unused' so any values you put in there will be ignored. This means `myNeuralNetworkFunction(1,2,3)` does not do what you think. If you read the documentation at the top of the code, it tells you what it is expecting: 
`%   X = 1xTS cell, 1 inputs over TS timsteps
%   Each X{1,ts} = 24xQ matrix, input #1 at timestep ts.

% where Q is number of samples (or series) and TS is the number of timesteps.`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the neural network: I didn’t fully read your code but usually you can think about the training step as first making a prediction and then correct it based on the learning paradigm. so to classify basically you just perform the first part (until you get the estimated output) with your trained weights.

Note that the output of a sigmoidal node (which is one of the most used transfer functions at the output of a classification network) is not a probability but can at some extent be thought as one. if you have 3 outputs, each with a value between 0 and 1, and knowing that the closest an output node is to 1 the more probable it is that the input match that class, then you can simply do: Pn(i)=On(i)./sum(On), where Pn(i) is the probability of node(or class) i, On(i) is the output of the node i.

Summing up: Learning_step=predict+Learning_paradigm, Probabilistic_Classification_Step=predict/sum(predict)